# PHP Database Query instead of using 0 and 1 use true or false/ paid or unpaid

Tags: php, mysql, database

new Query

```
$query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM payments $sCriteria";
$result         = mysql_query($query) or die("Error encountered on retrieving logs.");
$query_data     = mysql_fetch_row($result);
$numrows        = $query_data[0];
$rows_per_page  = 30;
$lastpage       = ceil($numrows/$rows_per_page);
$pageno         = (int)$pageno;

if ($pageno > $lastpage) {
    $pageno = $lastpage;
}
if ($pageno < 1) {
    $pageno = 1;
}

$limit          = "LIMIT ".($pageno - 1) * $rows_per_page .",".$rows_per_page;
$rs             = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM payments $sCriteria ORDER BY pay_date DESC $limit") or die("Error encountered on retrieving logs.".mysql_error());
$current_rows   = mysql_num_rows($rs);

if ($current_rows) {
    while ($rows = mysql_fetch_array($rs)) {
        echo "<tr>
                <td>".date("m/d/Y n:H:s",strtotime($rows["pay_date"]))."</td>
                <td>".$rows["po_no"]."</td>
                <td>".$rows["or_no"]."</td>
                <td>".$rows["sold_to"]."</td>
                <td>Php ".number_format($rows["amt_to_pay"],2,".",",")."</td>
                <td>Php ".number_format($rows["amt_paid"],2,".",",")."</td>
                <td>".$rows["pay_status"]."</td>
                **<td>".$rows["verified"]."</td>**
                <td><a href='pay_preview.php?id=$iPayID' class='action preview' title='Print Preview'><img src='images/preview.png' class='action_img' /></a></td>
```

Old Query

```
$query          = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM payments";
$result         = mysql_query($query) or die("Error encountered on retrieving payment details.");
$query_data     = mysql_fetch_row($result);
$numrows        = $query_data[0];
$rows_per_page  = 10;
$lastpage       = ceil($numrows/$rows_per_page);
$pageno         = (int)$pageno;

if ($pageno > $lastpage) {
    $pageno = $lastpage;
}
if ($pageno < 1) {
    $pageno = 1;
}
$limit          = "LIMIT ".($pageno - 1) * $rows_per_page .",".$rows_per_page;
$rs             = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM payments ORDER BY pay_date DESC, po_id $limit") or die("Error encountered on retrieving payment details.");
$current_rows   = mysql_num_rows($rs);

if ($current_rows) {
    while ($rows = mysql_fetch_array($rs)) {
        $iPayID     = $rows["pay_id"];
        $iPoID      = $rows["po_id"];
        $dSubTotal  = get_po_subtotal($iPoID);
        $sPoNo      = get_value("po","po_no","WHERE po_id=$iPoID");
        $iDis       = get_value("po","discount","WHERE po_id=$iPoID");
        $dNet       = $dSubTotal - ($dSubTotal * ($iDis/100));
        $sStat      = $rows["pay_status"];

        switch($sStat) {
            case "Paid":    $sColor = "class='blue'";break;
            default:        $sColor = "";break;
        }

        if ($rows["verified"]) {
            $sVerified = "Yes";
        }
        else {
            $sVerified = "No <a href='payment_verification.php?id=$iPayID' class='action verify' title='Verify' id='$iPayID'>(verify)</a>";
        }
        echo "<tr>

                <td>".date('Y-m-d',strtotime($rows["pay_date"]))."</td>
                <td>".$rows["or_no"]."</td>
                <td>$sPoNo</td>
                <td>".$rows["sold_to"]."</td>
                <td class='right'>Php ".number_format($rows["amt_to_pay"],2,".",",")."</td>
                <td class='right'>Php ".number_format($rows["amt_paid"],2,".",",")."</td>
                <td $sColor>".$rows["pay_status"]."</td>
                <td>$sVerified</td>
                <td><a href='pay_preview.php?id=$iPayID' class='action preview' title='Print Preview'><img src='images/preview.png' class='action_img' /></a></td>
              </tr>\n";
    }
}
```

My problem is that on my new query I can't change the Verified output to Paid or Unpaid, It stays with a 0 and 1 ** I did also copy and compare it with my old and new query, it just that it didn't work, can someone help me with it? thank you so much.

Comment: didn't get you, what you want.

Comment: I need to change the 0 and 1 to Unpaid and Paid

Comment: switch($sStat) {
                                case "Paid":    $sColor = "class='blue'";break;
                                default:        $sColor = "";break;
                            }

                            if ($rows["verified"]) {
                                $sVerified = "Yes";
                            }
                            else {
                                $sVerified = "No <a href='payment_verification.php?id=$iPayID' class='action verify' title='Verify' id='$iPayID'>(verify)</a>";
                            }
                            echo "<tr>

Comment: That's on my old query, It's just that I can't use it on my new one, and I don't know why.

Comment: do you want it in new query?

Comment: Yes. I want it on my new query

Comment: @fujichaan explain the part in new query if you have problem in that. What code you tried there

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest something like as an example to use a condition in mysql:
I your SQL statement specify the columns and don't use `SELECT *`

```
SELECT IF(Field > 0,'TRUE','FALSE') AS verified FROM Table
```

You can add a field to change it to `paid` or `unpaid` as well

```
SELECT IF(Field > 0,'Paid','Unpaid') AS verified FROM Table
```

Serves as an example. you can add any condition and result output

ALSO

In you code I cannot determine where  `$sVerified` is ever assigned a value?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure exactly what your asking.. I don't know if your needing to print the value to the page, or if your needing to change it for another query..

Maybe a switch case would work.. Allowing you to change the format to however you need it. Basically converting your old queries result so your new query can handle it..

```
$value = 0;  // or false.. this is your value from first query
$newval = null;  // just placeholder for newval in switch

switch($value) {
    case 0:
        $newval = 'Unpaid';
        break;
    case 1:
        $newval = 'Paid';
        break;
    default:
        $newval = 'Unknown';
}

echo $newval;
```